# How do I create/set a new metadata to an azure blob and get the metadata by using Python API?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have such metadata:

```
    Container: mycontainer
        Object: myblob
  Content Type: application/octet-stream Charset=UTF-8
Content Length: 26
          ETag: "0x8D18C1E18C0CF2C"
```

I want to add more metadata, like:

```
     Meta Century: Nineteenth
       Meta Author: Mustafa
```

After addition, it should be:

```
     Container: azure
        Object: myblob
  Content Type: application/octet-stream Charset=UTF-8
Content Length: 26
          ETag: "0x8D18C1E18C0CF2C"
  Meta Century: Nineteenth
   Meta Author: Mustafa
```

I need the function that **set** and **get** those **metadata**?

Answer (score 11):

This **Python** codes *sets* and *gets* the metadata of an azure "**blob**" in a "**container**":

```
from azure.storage import BlobService
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

# set metadata to "myblob" of container "mycontainer"
blob_service.set_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",
                               blob_name="myblob",
                               x_ms_meta_name_values={"Meta Century":"Nineteenth","Meta Author":"Mustafa"})

#get metadata of "myblob" of container "mycontainer"
metadata = blob_service.get_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",blob_name="myblob")
print metadata
```

the above code "only" returns the metadata that is set by the user by using

`blob_service.set_blob_metadata(....)` line of code.

If you need the content-type or other metadata(headers) you should use:

```
blob_service.get_blob("mycontainer", "myblob").__dict__["properties"]
```

Comment: Looks like there is a get_blob_properties() method now that avoids having to peak behind the scenes at the dictionary, e.g.    blob_service.get_blob_properties("mycontainer", "myblob"), will return all the properties including the user set metadata.